# In general, is working in New York a good choice for an IT professional?

Tags: work-environment, new-job, location

Compared to California, is New York a good city for an IT professional to work in?

I'm thinking about evaluating in terms of

- avg. compensation package
- cost of living
- Job opportunities available (in case one choose to switch jobs)
- avg. working hours per day (or do people tend to work overtime)
- overall "happiness"

(Feel free to add more evaluation criteria.)

I'd like to have your opinion on this.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. My opinion is NO. NY seems to offer bigger compensation packages, but the city also has a higher cost of living. Therefore the margin (income-cost) is lower than California. California wins on "job opportunities available" because it has several major IT companies. California may lose on the working hours because I heard people there tend to work long hours. In terms of "happiness", I think California wins because it has a large population of IT professionals. An IT professional would feel happier surrounded by other IT professionals.

Comment: but it is the non IT literate that provides the business...

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for the comment. Can you clarify a little bit on what the non IT literate is?

Comment: that depends on what you mean by an IT professional.

Comment: @SolarMike By IT professional, I mean software engineer, technical solution engineer. Basically people who make a living by their coding skills.

Comment: All of these except cost of living and job opportunities depend on the company you work for. Cost of living is probably not a factor if you're working at eg. FAANG, job opportunities are obviously better in Sillicon Valley (unless you want to work in a specific field like maybe finance). That's all there is to it, this question can't really be answered.

Comment: I always read that finding a place to live is hard in California. Pay doesn't make the difference as everybody is paid well.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the comment. I don't really agree on the cost of living is not a factor for FAANG employees. Some of my friend works for FANNG and they complain about the rising house prices and not being able to save any money if you have a mortgage. About the job opportunities, I'm thinking the same. About the "happiness" part, would you say most Silicon Valley companies have happier culture than NY companies?

Comment: You also need to ask about management cultures. California has a reputation for a different style than NY has. But each company is different.

Comment: Regarding working on site at a FAANG, the entire, total, complete issue is cost of living.  The ONLY reason to work for a faang is that you believe that you will make a wad of money from the stock aspect, after (say, whatever) 10 or 15 years.  They don't pay particularly well, and you have a disgusting life living in a shitbox house at 10,000 a month rent for an appalling little family house, grinding it out for a decade hoping for some sort of stock payoff.

Comment: one point @Emma "avg. working hours per day" the whole notion of programmers working "incredibly long hours" (the sort of "geeky" era) is long gone.  It is seen as "bad" if you work more than a normal (or indeed short) day.  You're a "bad programmer" if you work long hours; you're an unprofessional hacky cowgirl. If a company went  for the "long hours" approach like decade ago, it would just signal they are completely incompetent, do not have modern architecture and systems, and have useless "hacker" staff. That era is long gone. Programming has a "scientific" or "corporate" look now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simply "No", you might as well ask

- "Is it better to live in Hollywood or Ohio if I am in the film industry"

or

- "Is it better to live in Wall St or Maine if I am in the financial industry"

or

- "Is it better to live in Nevada or Colorado if I make gambling equipment"

Do note though that these days, there is no reason to not work "remotely".  NY is a shithole, it was cool in the 70s maybe. It is as exciting as living in a downmarket mall.  California is a huge and varied state but it would be utterly pointless to live in one of the hyper-high rent areas.

What possible reason would one have to not work remote?

(Indeed at first I assumed the question meant "work for" a Cali/EastCoast company, while of course living anywhere you want, Sudan, Tennessee, Belgium, whatever.)

Comment: 100% agree. I've worked in both SF and NYC, and hands down in SF you meet more people in your industry, and find more places to talk shop, than NYC. NYC is great if you are in IB or finance generally. Working in IT in banking in NYC is not cool though - you're not a revenue maker, you're an ops person.

Comment: indeed, you've hit the nail on the head @bharal

Comment: Thanks Fattie@ for the answer and bharal@ for sharing the opinion. What you wrote are exactly what I'd like to know. And I agree working remotely is definitely the best choice. But not all employer offers such opportunities.